# Spawn tasks based of output from unfinished upstream tasks in AirFlow

Tags: python, airflow, etl

I have one but potentially multiple tasks running in parallel that produce output files and each line of those files shall be used as an input parameter to start new tasks downstream. I wanted to not have to wait for completion of the upstream before starting these downstream ones. A few considerations:

- the upstreams may rely on 3rd party containers that I prefer to not modify
- It's possible that some of these lines may be repeated or contain unrelated data so they need to go through a processing function that can filter out duplicated / undesirable entries.

Here is my attempt using dynamic task mapping:

```
from datetime import datetime
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from airflow.operators.docker_operator import DockerOperator
from docker.types import Mount 
from airflow.models.dagrun import DagRun
from airflow.models.taskinstance import TaskInstance
from airflow.operators.dagrun_operator import TriggerDagRunOperator
from airflow import XComArg

import os
import time

dag = DAG('main', description='finds subdomains',
          schedule_interval=None,
          start_date=datetime(2023, 2, 1), catchup=False)

# this is my upstream task that produces an output file
subfinder = DockerOperator(task_id='subfinder', image='projectdiscovery/subfinder',
                                command="-d google.com -o /result/output.txt",
                                mounts=[Mount(source='/file/path',
                                              target='/result',
                                               type='bind')],
                                docker_url="unix://var/run/docker.sock",
                                tty=True,
                                dag=dag) 

# this is the function I want to call for each line of the output file from above
def test_function(target: str):
    print("next_task called with: ", target)
    return

# auxiliary functions
def _get_task_filepath(task_id, base_location_path='/results', file_name='output.txt'):
    return os.path.join(base_location_path, task_id, file_name)

def _get_next_line(task_id, current_line):
    file_path = _get_task_filepath(task_id)
    if os.path.exists(file_path):
        output = open(file_path).read()
        output_lines = output.split('\n')
        if len(output_lines) > current_line + 1 and len(output_lines[current_line + 1].strip()):
            return output_lines[current_line + 1].strip(), len(output)
    return None, None

# checking for file additions before and after task completion
def my_main(**context):
    dr: DagRun = context["dag_run"]
    ti: TaskInstance = context["ti"]
    supervised_tasks = ['subfinder']
    final_states = ['success', 'failed', 'removed', 'upstream_failed']
    running_supervised_tasks = [task.task_id for task in dr.get_task_instances() if task.task_id in supervised_tasks and task.state not in final_states]
    output_progress = {key: (-1,-1) for key in supervised_tasks}
    processed_items = set()

    print("RUNNING_SUPERVISED_TASKS: ", running_supervised_tasks)
    while running_supervised_tasks:
        for task_id in running_supervised_tasks:
            output_item, file_size = _get_next_line(task_id, output_progress[task_id][0])
            while output_item:
                output_progress[task_id] = (output_progress[task_id][0] + 1, file_size)
                if output_item not in processed_items:
                    print(f'=============== starting new task [{output_item}]')
                    PythonOperator.partial(
                        task_id=f'next_task_${output_item}',
                        python_callable=test_function,
                        dag=dag).expand(op_args=[output_item])
                    processed_items.add(output_item)
                output_item, file_size = _get_next_line(task_id, output_progress[task_id][0])

        time.sleep(5)
        running_supervised_tasks = [task.task_id for task in dr.get_task_instances() if task.task_id in supervised_tasks and task.state not in final_states]

    print('=========ALL SUPERVISED TASKS STOPPED=========')
    # supervised tasks have completed but there could still be unprocessed output
    for task_id in supervised_tasks:
        file_path = _get_task_filepath(task_id)
        print(f"catching up with {task_id} [{file_path}]")
        if os.path.exists(file_path) and os.path.getsize(file_path) > output_progress[task_id][1]:
            output_item, file_size = _get_next_line(task_id, output_progress[task_id][0])
            print(output_item, file_size)
            while output_item:
                output_progress[task_id] = (output_progress[task_id][0] + 1, file_size)
                if output_item not in processed_items:
                    print(f'=============== starting new task [{output_item}]')
                    PythonOperator.partial(
                        task_id=f'next_task_${output_item}',
                        python_callable=test_function,
                        dag=dag).expand(op_args=[output_item])
                    processed_items.add(output_item)
                output_item, file_size = _get_next_line(task_id, output_progress[task_id][0])

process_subdomain_results = PythonOperator(
    task_id="start",
    python_callable=my_main,
    provide_context=True,
    dag=dag)

process_subdomain_results
subfinder
```

In my example, `subfinder` is the output file producing task and `test_function` is the python_callable that represents the downstream function. I supervise `subfinder` output from `process_subdomain_results` which checks every 5s for changes in its file as well for task completion. This code runs but new tasks never get spawned, probably because I'm doing something wrong with the use of `partial().expand()`. Guidance here is highly appreciated - thanks in advance.